# Pytorch how to convert each element of tensor into tensors?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

if I have tensor like this:

> tensor([ 0.5324, -0.1281,  0.0565,  0.0114])

and I want to convert into:

> tensor([ [0.5324], [-0.1281],  [0.0565],  [0.0114] ])

so each element is tensor itself. Is there any easy way to do this?
Thank you